# When to use mysqli_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I am wondering about sql injection and want to know when to use mysqli_real_escape_string.

Do I need to use it every time I have a WHERE clause in my query?

Comment: You need to escape all parameters in SQL queries that could potentially contain harmful characters. This is especially true of user input.

Comment: You should almost always be using bound arguments, not mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 3):

You should use mysqli_real_escape_string for any data that comes from the user or can't be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it when you include $_REQUEST "vars" in your query
eg.

```
 $query = "UPDATE foo set bar = '{$_GET['var']}' ..."

 $query = "INSERT INTO foo ('{$_POST['var']}',) ..."

 $query = "SELECT bla from foo WHERE bar = '{$_COOKIE['var']}'"
```

each of this querys must be mysqli_real_escape_string to provide injections ...

Comment: you mean i have to use mysqli_real_escape_string even in the value of the update statement like: `$query = "UPDATE foo set bar = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['var']) ..."` and also in WHERE clause like: `$query = "SELECT bla from foo WHERE bar = mysqli_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['var'])"`?

Answer (score 0):

You use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or any variation of it to make sure data form any user input field is properly escaped.

For example, you have a form with a few inputs. You click submit and the data is sent as a request to your PHP script. In your script you insert into a database the values the user posted.

If a user typed the following into an input field on user login for example:

```
' WHERE `username` = {x} AND password > 1;
```

There is potential for that person to have all of the data from the table you are working with. Using:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($input)
```

Would yield the above as:

```
\' WHERE `username` = {x} AND password > 1;
```

The escape string on the ' would stop a possible SQL injection attack from working.

That said there is no reason you should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as the PDO and bound parameters are far superior at deflecting a host of different SQL attacks / injection methods. Learn it and use it!

**Edit due to comments**

`%` and `_` will also need special treatment above and beyond `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

```
function escape_extra_chars ( $string )
{
    $string = preg_replace("/\%/", "\%", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/\_/", "\_", $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Along those lines anyways (that func is untested)

Comment: hi, i am actually using prepared statement on my other script but since i have ported most of my script from mysql to mysqli i have a lot of sql statement that is using a traditional programming. so instead of using prepared statement, i decided to use mysqli_query instead of modifying all my code to use prepared statement. so for the meantime is it safe to use code like: `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])`?

Comment: @jaypabs yes you can use it like that, and it will provide a level of security, however it doesn't escape strings that contain special chars: `%` and `_` that are used in LIKE clauses. As they are usually contained within double quotes in the query they are still a risk. (see ammended info in my answer)

Comment: does this mean that we really have to use prepared statement? what happened to `mysqli_query`? is `mysqli_query` already useless?

Comment: Prepared statements provide you with a much more robust defense than mysqli or mysql could ever do out of the box. Managing all user inputted data in the fashion described above gets very tedious indeed. And, I wouldn't say `mysqli` was dead, but it is certainly the least preferred choice.

Comment: Worth mentioning that whether you're using PDO or not you should also always use 'htmlspecialchars()` as well (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when inputting into a db